# How to verify that input is a positive integer in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create an input that will Verify the input is an Integer, and that it is positive. Right now i have this. How should i check if the integer is positive

EDIT: Also i need it to keep asking until you enter a positive integer

```
        /**
 * pre: none
 * post: returns a positive integer as entered by the user
 */
public static int getInput(){
    int a;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Desired Quantity.");

    while (!scan.hasNextInt()){ //Checks if input is Integer
        System.out.println("Enter A Positive Integer");
        scan.next();

    }
    a = scan.nextInt(); //Assigns entered integer to a
    return a; //replace with correct code
}
```

Comment: Mathematically, how would you check this?

Comment: low quality question.... should have searched `google` first

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Scanner to validate user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021130/using-scanner-to-validate-user-input)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a single loop, similar to the one that you have for skipping invalid input. However, since the loop needs to ensure two things (i.e. a number is entered, and that number is positive) you need to modify its body.

Since the input needs to be done at least once, a `do`/`while` loop is a better choice.

Start with a loop that satisfies the condition that you want, i.e. "I got a number, and that number is positive":

```
int num = -1;
do {
    // We'll provide content of this in a moment
} while (num <= 0);
```

Once the loop exits, you know that `num > 0`, so the only task now is to write a body of the loop that takes us closer to that goal.

Inside the loop we need to check that the user entered a number. If he did, we harvest that number; otherwise, we tell the user to try again:

```
System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer number: ");
if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
    num = scan.nextInt();
} else {
    System.out.println("I need an int, please try again.");
    scan.nextLine();
}
```

That's it - now you have a loop body that reads the value for you, and a loop condition that ensures that the value is positive on exit. Combine the loop with the loop body, and try it out. It should do the trick.

Comment: When i test this code , if i input a number such as -20, it does not show the "I need an int, please try again."

Comment: because -20 is a valid Integer.

Comment: @specializt You can add an unconditional prompt. See the edit for one way of doing it.

Comment: Yes but i specifically need positive integers only

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int number = input.nextInt();

if( number == 0)
{ System.out.println("Number is zero"); }
else if (number > 0)
{ System.out.println("Number is positive"); }
else 
{ System.out.println("Number is negative"); }
```

**On a side note:**

Check **[Math.signum()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum%28double%29)**

> Returns the signum function of the argument; zero if the argument is
>   zero, 1.0 if the argument is greater than zero, -1.0 if the argument
>   is less than zero.

Comment: How can i make this so it will keep asking for input until it is a positive integer

Comment: @Tolkingdom:- Put that in a do..while loop!

Comment: If i enter a Letter instead of a number it crashes the program

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static int getInput(){
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter Desired Quantity.");
   int a = scan.nextInt();
   while (a  < 0){ //Checks if input is Integer
       System.out.println("Enter A Positive Integer");
       a = scan.nextInt();

   }

   return a;
}
```